# Enviar info a tabla desde un modal con php

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Hola he leido pero de verdad no lo he logrado, este es m codigo

**index.php**

```
<form class="modal fade modal_edit" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" method="post" action="/../components/insertar.php" name="nuevoregistro">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content modal_notif">
        <div class="modal-header ">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><span class= " fa fa-user"></span> Agrega nueva persona</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- <label>ID</label> -->
            <!-- <input type="text" name="" id="mod_id" class="form-control input-sm"> -->
            <label>Nombre y Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" name="mod_nomb"   id="mod_nomb"   class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Teléfono</label>
            <input type="text" name="mod_email"  id=""  class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="mod_tel"    id=""    class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Comuna</label>
            <input type="text" name="mod_comuna" id="" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Creado</label>
            <input type="text" name="mod_create" id="" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Actualizado</label>
            <input type="text" name="mod_update" id="" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Estado</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mod_status" class="input-sm" value=""> <span>Activo</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Creo que mi problema estaria ahi porque me sale un error diciendo 
Notice: Undefined index: mod_nomb in C:\xampp\htdocs\britmedia\naw\tablas_dinamica\components\tabla.php on line 76

probe tratando de ver mediante el name de alguno de mis input pero no envia nada y no se por que , alguna sugerencia?

Comment: por si acaso he probado mi codigo de conexion , lectura e insertar y me funciona solo quiero ver por ahora por que no me esta enviando ninguna informacion con post

Comment: revisaste la pestaña de desarrollador del navegador, en especifico "Network" Para ver que datos estas enviando?

Comment: no, lo acabo de hacer y no envia nada jeje